# Should I add recyclerView and CardView in dependencies?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I use `RecylerView` and `CardView` in my app and this my dependencies in `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'co.ronash.pushe:android-lib:0.9.1'        
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.1.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }        
    compile('com.mikepenz:crossfadedrawerlayout:0.3.2@aar')
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.4.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:octicons-typeface:3.0.0.1@aar'

    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
    compile 'com.github.bluejamesbond:textjustify-android:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:LikeButton:0.2.0'
    compile project(':material_rey')
    }
```

my app works in kitkat correctly. Should I add these dependencies to my build.gradle or not? what is the difference?

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
```

I use Android Studio 2.0 . when I run my app on SAMSUNG A5 with android 5.1.1 (lollipop) my `RecyclerView` doesn't scroll and my `CardView` doesn't have shadow and corner. I try solutions suggested in SO such as adding `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` or adding margin .even change `xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to `xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` doesn't work.
Are these issues relative to dependencies?

Comment: Really I have another External libraries in my dependencies like picasso and material drawer.

Comment: Yes. You have to add them as library dependency..

Comment: But when I don't add them my app running successfully. why?

Comment: Then you have not made a recyclerview or cardview in your app. If you want to make these then, you have to add the dependencies otherwise not needed

Comment: what about scrolling issue in lollipop? Why is it happening?

Comment: @ suku I use them in my app. I think gradle use other libraries dependencies because they use `recyclerView` in their dependencies like material drawer. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[com.android.support:design:23.2.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) includes RecyclerView in it. While cardView is not mentioned in the link, but if you are not finding any errors, and cardview is rendering then, it too is included. Hence, you needn't add these to the dependencies.

Recyclerview will not scroll if its rows fit in the screen. You can raise separate SO questions for these.

Comment: could you explain more about recyclerView rows? it scrolls in kitkat but not in A5

Comment: lets say you have 5 rows/items in a recyclerview and their dimensions is such that they fit in the screen of your device. Then there is no need for scroll and hence, it won't be scrollable. So your A5 screen may be able to accommodate all the items of the recyclerview

Comment: :) . NO. my list has enough items for scrolling, there is items which not shown completely means need to be scrolled. there is a strange behavior: if I move up my finger on screen (scroll down), recycler doesn't show any change but if I go to another activity and come back I see the recycler scrolled down!!

Comment: raise another SO question with this issue. Add the code for your adapter and activity/fragment rendering the recyclerview

Comment: I raised it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37235950/android-support-features-dont-apear-in-android-l