# Android: support features don't appear in android L

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I use Android Studio 2.0 . I have used RecyclerView and CardView which *render properly on kitkat* but when the app is run on SAMSUNG A5 with android 5.1.1 (lollipop) the RecyclerView doesn't scroll and my CardView doesn't have elevation and corner.
I tried solutions suggested in SO such as adding
`card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` and adding margin.
Even changed
`xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`
to
`xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`
But these didn't work

This is my RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_cards_recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:background="#e0e0e0"

    />

RecyclerView GridRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.grid_cards_recyclerview);
        GridLayoutManager gll = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);

        GridRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gll);
        GridAdapter gridAdapter = new GridAdapter(getActivity(), mylist);
        GridRecyclerView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
```

this is a strange behavior: if I move up my finger on screen (scroll down), recyclerview doesn't show any change but if I go to another activity and come back I see the recyclerview has scrolled down!! How do you explain this behavior?! Recyclerview recognizes scroll motion but doesn't show its reaction and doesn't update its view!

Comment: I think the problem may be because the recyclerview is covering the entire layout. Put the recyclerview inside a linearlayout/ relativelayout. I think the recyclerview may be confused with the match_parent height width. Try to make it wrap_content or provide some value in dp

Comment: I put the recyclerView with height="wrap_content" in a linearLayout with height="match_parent" but not work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved RecyclerView issue. [I searched a lot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731107/fragments-transaction-replace-on-api-21-is-staying-behind). I write my code in a fragment and for previewing them I used

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_main,
                fragment);
```

so in lollipop my fragment went behind the previous fragment and didn't handle touches so now I use

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_main,
                    fragment);
```

Now `recyclerView` is scrolling.

For shadow I used `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` but didn't work because I set `android:hardwareAccelerated` in Manifest to false. Making it true solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0

(With version prior to 22.2.0 it didn't work for me either)

Comment: I use com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1.